# CSS putting layers in order

Tags: css, layer

The Html below describes an updated version of layout I'm transferring from an old website that needs to be translated from images held in tables to pure CSS (or as close as I can get).

```
 <div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#about"><span class="LpTopLink">Link4</a>
      <a href="#contact"><span class="ETopLink">Link3</a>
      <a href="#news"><span class="YpTopLink">Link2</a>
      <a href="#home"><span class="HTopLink">Home</a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="titleA">Aspir...<span class="titleB">Fut...</span></h1>
<div id="videoBox">
  <p> <span class="welcome">Welcome...<span></p>
<p class="filmpar">
<a id="activator"><img src="images/Film-2.png" class="film"></a>
Lots of text to do with the project, over 4 or five lines, with an image and some decorative text links...</p>
<div id="activator2">
<div id="filmtxt"> link to film... </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page-wrapBody">
  <div class="div" id="one"></div>
  <div class="div" id="two"></div>
  <div class="div" id="three"></div>
</div>
```

The three coloured boxes at the bottom should be under the  (layer 3) but I can't seem to get them to slide under and sit on  (layer 3)

Below are the CSS links; first one for the videoBox and the second for the wrapBody. The wrapBody contains the detail of the three coloured boxes.

```
#videoBox {
  font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold,Helvetica Rounded,Arial,sans-serif;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  border: solid 6px;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -37;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f5991c, #f5be74);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#f5991c, #f5be74);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 6px #cac9c8;
  z-index:10;
}
```

wrapBody and coloured boxes

```
#page-wrapBody
  {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 80px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px grey;
    z-index:2;
  }
  .div
    {
      display:inline-block;
      width:33%;
      height:100%;
      margin-top: -60px;
      z-index:3;
  }
  #one {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ddffcc, #fff);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ddffcc, #fff);
  }
  #two {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffccd4, #fff);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ffccd4, #fff);
  }
  #three {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ccdeff, #fff);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ccdeff, #fff);
  }
```

If the images is shown, it shows what this codes produces, but I need the coloured boxes to sit under the videoBox (layer3) and preserve the shadow effect. Any help is appreciated!
[image: layers]

Comment: I've taken out the z-index to see if I can rearrange the layers, but even removing them doesn't effect any of the layout. Can anyone suggest what might be wrong with it?

Comment: Taking out `z-index` won't change anything because `z-index` was not being applied in the first place. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use z-index, you need to use the `position` property as well.

(emphasis mine)

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a **positioned element** and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.
>
> [...]
>
> For a positioned box (that is, one with **any position other than static**), the z-index property specifies:
>
> 1. The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> 2. Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.
>
> <sub>[z-index | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)</sub>

The alteration you'll need to make is in `#videoBox`. It would not hurt to make the same change wherever you are using `z-index`. But technically you only need to make the one adjustment.

```
#videoBox {
  ...
  z-index:10;
  position: relative; // add this line
}
```

[Here is a rough example](https://jsfiddle.net/74p0eqdg/)

---

A comment on your code, you appear to have unclosed `<span>` tags on lines 3-6. This may cause you issues if you leave it like that.

Comment: seriously! 1 line fixed it! Thanks amflare